# Let IntelliJ Formatter keep semicolon in a different line in Enums

Tags: intellij-idea, code-formatting

How do I enforce IntelliJ Formatter to keep the semi-colon in a different line in enums?

```
public enum ExampleEnum {
  A("a"),
  B("b"),
  C("c")
  ;
}
```

To keep git diffs clean I don't want it to be formatted into something like that:

```
public enum ExampleEnum {
  A("a"),
  B("b"),
  C("c");
}
```

I already looked into Formatter settings but couldn't find the right setting.

Comment: There is a request for exactly this formatting option already: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-151870. Feel free to vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by CrazyCoder in the comments there is an open [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-151870) for that.
So for now it is not possible.